# google dense_hash_map resize to pre-allocation does not work

Tags: c++, memory-management, hashmap

I have a large number of key/value pairs, say twenty million, to
insert into the dense_hash_map. I noticed that there are several times
of re-allocation happens in the process of inserting, and the peak
value of memory allocation is double than required. **In order to reduce
the total times of re-allocation and gain more efficiency**, I'm
considering about preallocation.

So I wrote:

```
dense_hash_map<k, v> m;
m.resize(20000000);
m.set_empty_key(0);
m.set_deleted_key(-1);
```

to do the preallocation, and after set_empty_key, I saw a big
700MBytes allocation in the memory, so far so good.

But, after first few(say 4 to 5) insert/erase calls, the big memory
block will be freed, and dense_hash_map repeats the re-allocation
until 1.2GBytes (peak value is 2.3GBytes).

What should i do please ?

Comment: use `dense_hash_map<k, v>(20000000)` to construct instead

Comment: @RedAlert It's the same meanning.

Answer (score 0):

The dense_hash_map will automatically shrink the hash to fit the amount of data. To prevent an automatic shrink you have to set the min_load_factor